# PowerMockito mocked private method throws exception but returns expected response

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I have mocked private method which makes REST call using PowerMockito.

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(response).when(notificationService, "sendNotification", anyString());
```

When tests run, it provides mocked response and assertions work as I expect.

However, during tests I see:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
```

Because mocked private method may be executed:

```
private NotificationResponse sendNotification(String notification) {

    URL url = new URL(exampleURL);
    // more code
}
```

How to avoid mocked method execution?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a valid `exampleUrl` in your test.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid method execution?